# CustomValidator handler not being called after user clicks the Update link on the GridView

Tags: asp.net, gridview

On the DropDownList SelectedIndexChanged, the page posts back and records the name of the developer in the radiobutton. When the user clicks the Update link on the GridView, I want the **customValidator** to check if the **Radiobutton is empty**.

```
<EditItemTemplate>
   <table>
       <tr>
          <td>
              <asp:DropDownList ID="_ddlAllDev" runat="server" AutoPostBack = "true" DataTextField = "Text"
                   DataValueField = "Value" OnSelectedIndexChanged = "ddlAllDev_SelectedIndexChanged">
              </asp:DropDownList>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>
              <asp:RadioButtonList ID="_rblAllDev" runat="server" AutoPostBack = "true" DataTextField = "Text"
                   DataValueField = "Value" OnSelectedIndexChanged = "rblAllDev_SelectedIndexChanged">
              </asp:RadioButtonList>
              <asp:CustomValidator ID="_valDev" runat="server" ControlToValidate = "_rblAllDev" Text = "*" 
                   ErrorMessage="Please choose at leat one developer for this task" OnServerValidate = "AllDev_ServerValidate" />
           </td>
        </tr>
     </table>    
</EditItemTemplate>
```

The problem is that it looks like the CustomerValidator handler is not even being called after the user click the UPPDATE link on the GridView. I have put a break point inside the method but the method is not even being called.

```
protected void AllDev_ServerValidate(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{

}
```

Am I missing something?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Add `ValidationGroup` To your validation control and button

Comment: Which control, RadioButtonList and/or CustomValidator? Also, the control that causing the postback is a link on the GridView, it's called UPDATE.

Comment: CustomValidation control and aboutyour Update link - is that custom link button or auto generated edit link?

Comment: No the UPDATE that comes with GridView when you setup ShowEditingButton = "true". I've tried to buttonType = Button or Link, I still don't get the result.